# What is the difference between creating a part of flutter code as widget and variable

Tags: dart, flutter

I saw some places a block of code assigned to a widget or to variable, what is the difference between creating both?

**a sample code below:**

```
  //creating new widget

  Widget ratingSection = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [ ..............
    ],
  ),
);

//creating new var

 var ratingSectionVar = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [ ..............
    ],
  ),
);

return MaterialApp( ......
     ....
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ratingSection,
        ratingSectionVar,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart  provide something called [Type inference](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/sound-dart#type-inference)

> The analyzer can infer types for fields, methods, local variables, and
>   most generic type arguments. When the analyzer doesn’t have enough
>   information to infer a specific type, it uses the dynamic type.

so when you create variables using the `var` keyword you get the type from the right side of the assignment statement 
so  `var ratingSectionVar = Container()`
means that the Type of `ratingSectionVar`  is `Container` which is also derived from `Widget` class